# When using a domain class in Controller it is returning a error when testing that controller is done

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I have a controller written in grails where i have used name of a domain class to retrieve data from db. Now I want to test it using grails default test.

But it is returning a error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Either class [cre_service.AppPreferences] is not a domain class or GORM has not been initialized correctly or has already been shutdown. Ensure GORM is loaded and configured correctly before calling any methods on a GORM entity.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to Mock you domain class e.g.

```
import spock.lang.Specification
import grails.test.mixin.Mock

@Mock( [AppPreferences] )
class YourControllerClassSpec extends Specification {
...
```

Comment: But it is returning a Null value when I print the response.text in grails test. But in grails localhost controller is rendering the correct value that is present in the database.

Comment: What are you returning to gsp? is it a render statement or a Map or...?

Comment: I have to render a map from db .  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713888/accessing-the-data-in-db-via-domain-class-in-controller-via-grails-testing

Comment: I've commented on your [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713888/accessing-the-data-in-db-via-domain-class-in-controller-via-grails-testing) question